# Is an aggregate function in a correlated subquery considered non-sargable?

Tags: t-sql, correlated-subquery

we have some instances of code, similar to this simple example, located in views and itvfs. In some cases this is the most efficient code. The linter is throwing an error saying this is not sargable. My question, is this considered non-sargable?

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.order_id =
    (SELECT MAX(o2.order_id) AS max_order_id
    FROM orders o2
    WHERE c.customer_id = o2.customer_id)
```

Comment: I think you're missing the column alias on the correlated subquery.

Comment: Good catch, thank you.

Comment: What linter are you using? Didn't know there was a linter that advanced out there. Is this technically Sargable aka can this query use an index? I think it can use the indexes, so it's Sargable technically. But it queries the table twice and will not perform well. I'd recommend using OUTER APPLY TOP 1 or ROW_NUMBER() WHERE RowNum = 1. My guess is APPLY will perform better (assuming you have the correct indexes), but ROW_NUMBER() scales better with more customers with less orders per customer. If you have lots of orders per customer, APPLY will probably perform better.